# Issue Toggling Element Styles Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a page that has a row of images (multiple rows, 4 images per row).

Each image has text that describes the image.

I currently have it toggling using the Bootstrap collapse plugin. The content is positioned absolutely so it doesn't wrap the images under the content when opened. (The content sits just below the image) and pushes the next row of images down.

I am using jQuery to add a class when the image is open and to remove it when it is closed. I also have it resetting when another image is opened.

The issue I am having is when I open the first image, the dynamic margin I have given the image works the first time and then any time after it doesn't move past the reset I put in place. At this point, all elements are affected. However any of the other images seem to add/remove the margin I add based on the toggleClass just fine as long as i start with the second + image.

Here is the page that the code lives - http://comauto.bldsvr.com/meet-the-team/

Here is the jQuery I am using

```
$('.team .member-group .member-image').on("click", function () {
    $('.member-image').css({'margin-bottom': '0px'});
    $(this).toggleClass('open-member'); 
    $('.team .member-group .member-image').not(this).removeClass('open-member');
    $('.open-member').css({'margin-bottom': $('.member-content').height()});
});
```

Can anyone point out what may be making this seem buggy?

Comment: It seems my issue was with the transition bootstrap adds. The element was trying to determine its height before the content would load. If done too slowly, the element would still have 0 height and then render that way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my issue was with the transition bootstrap adds. The element was trying to determine its height before the content would load. If done too slowly, the element would still have 0 height and then render that way.

I added a delay to my code and now it works.

```
$('.team .member-group .member-image').on("click", function () {
    $('.team .member-group .member-image').not(this).removeClass('open-member');
    $(this).toggleClass('open-member');
    $(this).toggleClass('close-member');
    setTimeout(function (){

         $('.open-member').css({'margin-bottom': $('.member-content').height()});

     }, 500); // how long do you want the delay to be?  


});
```